# PHP CURL Authentication

Tags: php, curl

The documentation says like this:

```
curl —X POST -c cookies.txt —d "login=demo&password=demo42" https://www.myadcash.com/console/login_proxy.php
```

Output will be:

```
{"token":"6333531373034343433623663646836383165693937383167373264323334663"}
```

My current code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("login"=>"demo","password"=>"demo42"));

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.myadcash.com/console/login_proxy.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

No `JSON` response is showing. Although the text file is saving. Please help me to find right direction. Also if there is any error in the code, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-d "login=demo&password=demo42"` means data field, thats why pass as post fields not headers.

Therefore these two lines in your curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //Optional
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "login=demo&password=demo42");
```

and you must get output.
On the basis of documentation, credentials must be post fields not header that's why no need to put `login` and `password` on header.

You don't need

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("login"=>"demo","password"=>"demo42"));
```